# (Python) Is there a way to use google api to get the number of unread messages in inbox(110)?

Tags: python, google-api

[image]

I tried this api `https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/get?authuser=0#http-request` but the result is wrong

```
r=requests.get('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/INBOX', headers=headers)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                response = json.loads(r.text)
                return response['messagesUnread']
            else:
                return 0
```

The above code returns the result:

```
{
  "id": "INBOX",
  "name": "INBOX",
  "messageListVisibility": "hide",
  "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
  "type": "system",
  "messagesTotal": 8516,
  "messagesUnread": 8043,
  "threadsTotal": 8025,
  "threadsUnread": 7640,
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Well, the unread messages show next to the Inbox is mainly from the Primary category, however that doesn't seems to have an ID,
the way to go around it, by fetching unread messages from each category and subtract that from the overall unread messages, bad solution but I couldn't find another way to do it.